# "Next X Hours" filter is not working as expected in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have added a custom field named "due by" in queueitem entity. Then I created a system view named "Calls due next 1 hour" again in the queueitem entity with filter condition as:

Field: due by       Filter: **Next X Hours**        Value: 1

But this view seems to behave wrongly. E.g. Suppose current system time is say **H:MM** AM/PM, then this view is displaying all the records which are due by till **H+1:59** AM/PM. While I am expecting it to display all the records which are due by till **H+1:MM** AM/PM only.
 Because of this issue, my custom view is displaying records in the range or around next 1 - 2 hours. E.g. if the current system time is 10:01 AM it displays records till 11:59 AM which is around 2 hours whereas if current system time is 10:59 AM, it again displays records till 11:59 AM which is 1 hour.

This seems to be a bug in "Next X Hours" filter of CRM because I have checked it for some other entities as well by creating a custom view with "Next X Hour" filter where X is set to 1 and all are displaying records till **59th minute of next hour**.

I have posted this issue here just to confirm whether this is really a bug or only I am facing this.

Thanks

Comment: [This article](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.com/2012/07/date-and-time-operators-in-crm-explained.html) says that it should behave as you are expecting. However, it says that Last X Hours behaves like you're seeing for next X hours. They may have changed it up, but what you're seeing is definitely a contradiction of the article

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. I have already gone through this article and surprised to see that scenario given for "Last X Hours" is also applicable for "Next X Hours" in my case, though the article says nothing about this. That is the reason I want to get this confirmed.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your server is not off by an hour?

Comment: We have 2 different installations of CRM 2011 both on different time zones and I am getting this issue on both of the CRM servers. And yes I have checked the server time...it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I see in a lot of CRM views' pre-built filters, especially around date fields - the name of the field does not really indicate what it will do.  In addition to your example, the "Last Year" filter to me would indicate that it should return results from the last 365 days ("in the last year"), but in reality it returns all results where the calendar year is equal to current year - 1 (same with last month, last week, next year, next month, etc.).  Your question seems to be about the same concept (the next 1 hour is where hour = current hour + 1).

The only solution is to be sure to test out all the filters so you know exactly how they behave instead of relying on how you interpret the wording.  It's a bit obnoxious, but it has to be done.